# Trying to get the correct letter l lowercase

Tags: fonts, packages

I would like to get the $l(g)$ of the left side, but using

```
\mathcal{}
```

I get the right side:

[image]

Please, what package can I use?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `\ell` in math mode, there is no caligraphic lowercase font

Comment: Thanks! It worked!!!  :)

Comment: A special case of [How to look up a symbol or identify a letter from a math alphabet or other character? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-letter-from-a-math-alphabet-or-other-chara) .

Answer (score 1):

It's l with a script (handwriting) shape. You needn't to invoke any package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$\ell(g)$

\end{document}
```